# Apache NetBeans: JavaFX Error: Missing javafx.fml, javafx.controls,

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I was trying to load a **HelloFX** java program and it gave me this error after successfully building and cleaning the code. I have open **jfk 14.0.1** installed as a library classpath,

> JavaFX14

and am running JDK 14 as well. I also added

> --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml

to the VM options in the Run tab. I've heard before that the solution to this is to add
*requires javafx.controls* to my main directory ( **src/main/java** ) but I don't know how to locate that whether that is referring to my IDE or in a file.

The line where the exception is thrown is at line 17 or
`public class HelloFX extends Application`

I added options  `--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,` and `javafx.fxml`

EDIT: I've removed the space between `javafx.controls,` and `javafx.fml` and now I've received this error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found C:\Users\fross\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Users\fross\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Could someone please show me what I'm doing wrong, here or how to fix this?

Comment: no screenshots of text ..

Comment: can you provide the stack trace.

Comment: Where do I find the stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure how the text would help, but I'll add the code in an edit as well as the options I added.

Comment: @DjMaxLETU You have `--add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml`. The space you have after the comma makes it treat `javafx.fxml` as a separate argument (and apparently it interprets it as the main class in your case). Get rid of that space.

Comment: edit the question with further details (vs. stuffing them into hard-to-read comments)

Comment: _I'm not sure how the text would help_ it's readable - screenshots are not ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set the module path you have to specify every jar, since the jar files are the ones containing the modules and not the folders, it should be like this:

```
--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Comment: That didn't work man. It still gave me the same error message.

Comment: die you actually try that? module-path expects a directory (not a jar) ..

Comment: yes i did try that, and yes it did work, as long as the jar is modular